# Given that random variable $X$ is the sum of two independent fair dice, what is $E(4X^3 + 5)$ and $SD(4X^3 +5)$?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value, variance

$E(X)=7$ and $Var(X)=5.83333$,

Here is my working:

Given that $E(X)=7, E(X^3)=343$??, hence $E(4X^3+5)= 4$, $E(X^3)+5 = 1377$

and $SD(X) = 2.4152$, $SD(X^3)=14.09$ hence $SD(4X^3 +5) = 4SD(X^3) = 56.35$

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: We do not in general have $E(X^3)=E(X)^3$, unfortunately. Consider, for instance, a Bernoulli variable. Then $X^3=X$, but clearly $E(X^3)=E(X)\neq E(X)^3$.

Comment: is there a general formula to use for E(x^3) ?

Comment: Just use the definition? $X^3$ is $1$ with probability $\frac1{36}$, it is $8$ with probability $\frac1{18}$, it is $27$ with probability $\frac1{12}$, and so on. Should be quick enough if you have a calculator available.